# NodeJS throws module_not_found

Tags: node.js, module, require

When I'm importing modules using require, it throws a MODULE_NOT_FOUND error.
(mymain.js)

```
var counter = require(".\count");
var array=[10,20,30];
console.log(counter(array));
```

Here is the module that I'm trying to import(count.js)

```
 var counter = function(arr){
    return 'length= '+arr.length;
};
module.exports = counter ;
```

Both of these codes are in the same directory.
Node mymain throws the following error.

```
D:\Programming\NodeJS>node mymain
internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1017
  throw err;
  ^

Error: Cannot find module '.count'
Require stack:
- D:\Programming\NodeJS\mymain.js
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1014:15)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:884:27)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1074:19)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:72:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (D:\Programming\NodeJS\mymain.js:1:15)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1185:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1205:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1034:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:923:14)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (internal/modules/run_main.js:71:12) {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  requireStack: [ 'D:\\Programming\\NodeJS\\mymain.js' ]
}
```

Comment: You need to use ./count instead of .\count in the require module line

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have used backward slash in the require module statement, that won't work. The correct way is to use forward slash like this:

`var counter = require("./count");`

The backward slash works as an escape character.